# VPS rbenv location directory is wrong when using Capistrano3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rbenv, capistrano3, centos7

My Centos 7 has rbenv located in `/root/.rbenv`, but when I run `cap production deploy:setup_config` it searches rbenv inside `/usr/local/rbenv`.

> Error Message

```
DEBUG [6a1407a4] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.0 ] as root@111.111.111.11
DEBUG [6a1407a4] Command: [ -d /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.0 ]
DEBUG [6a1407a4] Finished in 6.403 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
ERROR rbenv: 2.2.0 is not installed or not found in /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.0
```

> .bash_profile

```
# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
export PATH
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

> Gemfile

```
# Use Capistrano for deployment
group :development do
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler'
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv', github: "capistrano/rbenv"
end
```

> Capfile

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'

require 'capistrano/rbenv'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'

Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/*/*.rb').each { |r| import r }
```

Is rbenv supposed to be inside `/usr/local/`? Is something wrong in the configuration of the Capistrano? I've searched inside deploy.rb and the tasks inside `lib/capistrano/*`, but I found no reference of `/usr/local/`.

My references of the Capistrano setup are from this [git](https://github.com/crslade/todo-sunzi-deploy/blob/master/config/deploy.rb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem in [this line](https://github.com/crslade/todo-sunzi-deploy/blob/master/config/deploy.rb#L9). You should specify `:user` value for `rbenv_type` variable because you have installed rbenv to user directory.